# projected answers of a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I am studying linear programming and I try to solve this problem:

Let : S ⊂ $ℝ^n × ℝ^m$ and we define S′ as below:

S′:= { x ∈ $ℝ^n$ | ∃y ∈ $ℝ^m$ | ( x, y) ∈ S }, we call  S′ the projection of S onto x, Now I have to prove the projection of a polyhedron is also a polyhedron, I am trying to find a linear system that the projected answers are true in it, but I don't know how can I make that.Thanks for your help.

Comment: Projecting onto what?  Note that projecting onto a linear subspace is a linear operation.

Comment: I tried to answer your question by editing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just considere the following application:

$$\begin{align}\Phi: \mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R^m&\rightarrow\mathbb R^n\\
(x,y) &\mapsto x
\end{align}$$

By construction it is trivially linear $(\begin{align}\Phi(\lambda(x_1,y_1) +\mu(x_2, y_2))&=\Phi(\lambda x_1+\mu x_2,\lambda y_1+\mu y_2)\\&=\lambda x_1+\mu x_2\\&=\lambda\Phi(x_1,y_1)+\mu\Phi(x_2,y_2)\end{align})$, and it verifies $\Phi(S)=S^{'}$

It becomes evident that the image of a segment is a segment (possibly reduced to a point), and by generalization, the image of a polyhedron is also a polyhedron (all the segments of the source polyhedron are projected as segments in the image).

Comment: I think you are right. thanks for your answer.